# Error in my Code: Finding Prime Numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to take user input and run it through a loop against a tuple of predefined prime numbers by using a for loop inside of a while loop.  If the number we are checking has a remainder of zero using modulo, we know that it is a factor of the number.

What I am trying to do is output all of the factors of a number, append those factors to the numbers list, and at the end, output the prime number as well as appending the prime number to the numbers list.

The program works to a certain point.  However, when I attempt to use a number such as 82, it says there is only one factor, when in fact, my goal would be for it to say that the factors are 2 and 41, as an example.

My question is where am I going wrong in the code to prevent that from happening?

```
#Global tuple and list
prime = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31)
numbers = []

# main function
def main():
  # while loop to check on input, and catch value errors
  while True:
    try:
        j = int(input("Enter a positive integer between 1 and 1,000:"))
        j = abs(j)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer.")
        main()
    # call factor function, and pass j variable to function            
    l = factors(j)
    #return values from factors function, and print output
    print("The factors of {0} are :".format(j), " ".join(map(str, numbers)))

#def factors function
def factors(j):
    should_restart = True
    #while the loop is running perform calculations
    while should_restart:
    should_restart = False
    for i in prime:
        # if j is evenly divided, continue
        if j % i == 0:
            print("Output: {0}".format(i))
            #if j divided by i equals 1, must be prime
            if j/i == 1:
                numbers.append(i)
                continue
            #set j to j//i and restart the loop    
            else:
                j = j//i
                numbers.append(i)
                should_restart = True
                break
        else:
            continue
# call the main function
main()
```

Comment: You are now getting only 1 because 41 isn't in `prime` tuple. Instead of hardcoding primes, you can generate them up to some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- You state that you want to add to the *prime* tuple whenever you find a new prime. But tuples are immutable, so you better define it as a list then. On the other hand, there is not much use in adding primes, because you will not need them for input that is below 1000: whatever *j* is after dividing it by all other factors will be 1 or a prime. That is enough. It is of no use to add another prime to the list.
- The recursive call to `main` is unnecessary and would make the prompt for input appear too many times once you answer with invalid input. Just leave that call out -- the `while` loop will do the necessary already.
- As *numbers* is an list that the function *factors* produces, it is better to let it be the function's return value instead of defining it as a global variable.
- The variable *should_restart*, and the loop on it, lead to unnecessary many comparisons: you should only stick with the *same* divisor in a loop, until that divisor no longer divides the given number. You should also perform the division always. With such algorithm, there is no need to go back an try the previous divisors again.
- The condition `j/i == 1` is strange, because it is equivalent to `j == i`. Although this means *j* is prime, it can be combined with the other case. Instead, you could bring some savings by *exiting* the loop as soon as `j > i`. Then when after the loop you still have a value of *j* that is greater than 1, you could *assume* it is a factor (see next point).
- As you don't have all primes in the *prime* list, you must protect the code from producing wrong results for numbers that only have prime factors that are not in that list. This you did by setting the maximum input limit to 1,000. But you need to enforce this limitation, and reject input that violates this limit. You could also make it more generic by rejecting input that is greater than the product of the largest consecutive prime (+2) you have in the *prime* list.

Here is the adapted code:

```
prime = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31)
# define the maximum value that can be input
max_input = (prime[-1]+2)**2-1
# don't define numbers as global

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            j = int(input("Enter a positive integer between 1 and {}:"
                          .format(max_input)))
            if j >= 1 and j <= max_input: # check the input is in valid range
                break # OK!
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer.")
            # don't call main recursively here, just let the loop do its job
    numbers = factors(j) # return value is list of factors
    print("The factors of {0} are :".format(j), " ".join(map(str, numbers)))

def factors(j):
    numbers = [] # don't make this a global, but a return value
    for i in prime:
        if i > j: # exit when there is no probability for finding another factor
            break
        # if i is divisor of j, log and remove that factor
        while j % i == 0: # keep repeating
            # i is prime and a divisor, so add it as a factor 
            numbers.append(i)
            # always set j to j//i and try again with the same divisor    
            j = j//i
    if j > 1 and j not in prime: # need to add this non-listed prime as factor
        numbers.append(j)
    return numbers # return the list of factors

main() # call the main function
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review my code, and answer so concisely.